# How do you include jsm examples with three.js over nodes.js?

Tags: three.js

I installed three.js using npm install.
I work since month with three.js using the following single import:

```
import * as THREE from 'three'
```

Now it is the first time, I am trying to used a jsm example as described on https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/en/introduction/Installation:

```
import { OrbitControls } from 'three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
oc = new OrbitControls();
```

Now I get the following error:

```
[SyntaxError: 'import' and 'export' may appear only with 'sourceType: module'] {
```

It burns down to that the core three.js files import dependencies using

```
import { LineBasicMaterial } from './LineBasicMaterial.js';
```

but the jsm files import from three.module.js

```
import { SaderLib,ShaderMaterial,Vector2} from "../../../build/three.module.js";
```

So three.module.js is a different script "format"?

I guess, I have to change my gulpfile?

```
var bundler = watchify(browserify(['./src/index.js'], { debug: true}).transform(babel.configure({presets: ["es2015"]})))  // original
```

But I admit, that I never really fully understood this part.

Can't believe I am the first one running into this.
How do you include jsm examples with three.js over nodes.js?

Why do the js files under /src use a different include method than under /examples ?

Comment: I just saw there is also a "js" directory that contains the same files as the "jsm". However, the include of these files also fails, but with "ReferenceError: THREE is not defined".

Comment: This is a shot in the dark (because it depends on your compiler), but it might be solved with `import * as THREE from 'three/build/three.module.js'` instead of just `from 'three'`